# How to solve "Fail : Over Query Limit" error while calling SOAP webservice in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I have Soap web service and I want to call this webservice through C#. What I am doing is that first I am calling "GetToken" method to get  token and after that I am passing recieved token in "GetDetailedLastPositionData" method to get data from database. I want to get token only one time until it gives "Authentication failure" error.  I have tested this webservice in wsdlbrowser.com and its working fine. When I am calling this web service from C#, Mostly I am getting both "FAIL:OVER_QUERY_LIMIT", "Authentication failure" error.

LoginController.cs

```
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(string username,string password)
        {
            login obj_login = new login();
            string result = obj_login.InvokeService(username,password);
            Object result1 = obj_login.Update_btrunning_long_lat(result);
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new JsonContent(new
                {
                    //Success = true, //error
                    Message = result1 //return exception
                })
            };
        }
```

LoginModel.cs

```
public HttpWebRequest CreateSOAPWebRequest(string value)
    {
        //Making Web Request  
        HttpWebRequest Req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://abc/services.asmx");


        Req.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();
        //SOAPAction    
        Req.Headers.Add(@"SOAPAction:http://tempuri.org/" + value + "");
        //Content_type     
        Req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        Req.Accept = "text/xml";
        //HTTP method    

        Req.Method = "POST";
        //return HttpWebRequest    
        return Req;
    }

    public string InvokeService(string a, string b)
    {
        string query1 = "Select * from btrack.bt_sms_setting";
        MySqlDataAdapter daSetting = new MySqlDataAdapter(query1, conn);
        DataTable dtSettings = new DataTable();
        daSetting.Fill(dtSettings);
        //Calling CreateSOAPWebRequest method    
        HttpWebRequest request = CreateSOAPWebRequest("GetToken");
        IWebProxy proxy = request.Proxy;
        if (proxy != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Proxy: {0}", proxy.GetProxy(request.RequestUri));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Proxy is null; no proxy will be used");
        }

        WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
        Uri newUri = new Uri("http://192.168.20.20:3128");
        // Associate the newUri object to 'myProxy' object so that new myProxy settings can be set.
        myProxy.Address = newUri;
        // Create a NetworkCredential object and associate it with the 
        // Proxy property of request object.
        myProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(dtSettings.Rows[0]["username"].ToString(), Decrypt(dtSettings.Rows[0]["password"].ToString()));
        request.Proxy = myProxy;

        XmlDocument SOAPReqBody = new XmlDocument();
        //SOAP Body Request    
        SOAPReqBody.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>  
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-   instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">  
         <soap:Body>  
            <GetToken xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">  
              <UserName>" + a + @"</UserName>  
              <Password>" + b + @"</Password>  
            </GetToken>  
          </soap:Body>  
        </soap:Envelope>");

        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            SOAPReqBody.Save(stream);
        }
        //Geting response from request  




        WebResponse Serviceres = request.GetResponse();


        StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(Serviceres.GetResponseStream());
        //reading stream    
        var ServiceResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
        //writting stream result on console    
        return ServiceResult;
        //Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public string Invoke_Vehicle(string a)
    {
        string query1 = "Select * from btrack.bt_sms_setting";
        MySqlDataAdapter daSetting = new MySqlDataAdapter(query1, conn);
        DataTable dtSettings = new DataTable();
        daSetting.Fill(dtSettings);
        //Calling CreateSOAPWebRequest method    
        HttpWebRequest request = CreateSOAPWebRequest("GetDetailedLastPositionData");
        IWebProxy proxy = request.Proxy;
        if (proxy != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Proxy: {0}", proxy.GetProxy(request.RequestUri));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Proxy is null; no proxy will be used");
        }

        WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
        Uri newUri = new Uri("http://192.168.20.20:3128");
        // Associate the newUri object to 'myProxy' object so that new myProxy settings can be set.
        myProxy.Address = newUri;
        // Create a NetworkCredential object and associate it with the 
        // Proxy property of request object.
        myProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(dtSettings.Rows[0]["username"].ToString(), Decrypt(dtSettings.Rows[0]["password"].ToString()));
        request.Proxy = myProxy;

        XmlDocument SOAPReqBody = new XmlDocument();
        //SOAP Body Request    
        SOAPReqBody.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>  
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-   instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">  
         <soap:Body>  
            <GetDetailedLastPositionData xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">  
              <Token>" + a + @"</Token>  

            </GetDetailedLastPositionData>  
          </soap:Body>  
        </soap:Envelope>");
        //                  <vehicleid>" + b + @"</vehicleid>  
        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            SOAPReqBody.Save(stream);
        }
        //Geting response from request  




        WebResponse Serviceres = request.GetResponse();


        StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(Serviceres.GetResponseStream());
        //reading stream    
        var ServiceResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
        //writting stream result on console    
        return ServiceResult;
        //Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public string Update_btrunning_long_lat(string result)
    {
        string vehicle_detail = "";
        if (token_val == "")
        {
            token_val = convert_xml(result, "GetTokenResult/Token");
        }
        string query1 = "SELECT * FROM btrack.bt_bus;";
        MySqlDataAdapter daSetting = new MySqlDataAdapter(query1, conn);
        DataTable dtSettings = new DataTable();
        daSetting.Fill(dtSettings);
        if (dtSettings.Rows.Count > 0)
        {


            //for (int i = 0; i < dtSettings.Rows.Count; i++)
            //{
            //    Thread.Sleep(100);
            //vehicle_detail = Invoke_Vehicle(token_val, Convert.ToString(dtSettings.Rows[i]["bus_id"]));

                 vehicle_detail = Invoke_Vehicle(token_val);

                XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmldoc.LoadXml(vehicle_detail);
                XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("GetDataResult");
                string Short_Fall = string.Empty;
                string short_fall1 = string.Empty;
                foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
                {
                    Short_Fall = node.InnerText;
                }
                if (Short_Fall == "FAIL:OVER_QUERY_LIMIT")
            {
                return "fail";
            }
                if (Short_Fall == "Authentication failure")
                {
                    token_val = "";
                    return "token expire";
                }
                xmldoc.LoadXml(Short_Fall);

                XmlNodeList nodeList1 = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("DetailedPositions");

                foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList1)
                {
                    short_fall1 = node.InnerXml;
                }
                //xmldoc.LoadXml(short_fall1);


                XmlNodeList nodeList2 = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("postiondata");
                //XmlNodeList nodeList1 = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName(tag[1].ToString());
                //string return_result = string.Empty;
                string return_result1 = string.Empty;

                //foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList1)
                //{
                //    return_result1 = node.InnerText;
                //}
                foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList2)
                {
                    XmlNodeList CNodes = node.SelectNodes("/DetailedPositions/postiondata");
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("", conn);
                    cmd.CommandText = "truncate table btrack.bt_vehicle_location";
                    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                    }

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    //return_result = node.InnerText;
                    for (int i = 0; i < CNodes.Count; i++ )
                    {
                        string vehicle = CNodes[i]["vehicle"].InnerText;
                        string uid = CNodes[i]["uid"].InnerText;
                        string vehicleinfo = CNodes[i]["vehicleinfo"].InnerText;
                        string gpsupdatedtime = CNodes[i]["gpsupdatedtime"].InnerText;
                        string latitude = CNodes[i]["latitude"].InnerText;
                        string longitude = CNodes[i]["longitude"].InnerText;
                        string location = CNodes[i]["location"].InnerText;
                        string speed = CNodes[i]["speed"].InnerText;
                        string stop = CNodes[i]["stop"].InnerText;
                        string geofencelocation = CNodes[i]["geofencelocation"].InnerText;
                        string geofenceinout = CNodes[i]["geofenceinout"].InnerText;
                        string geofencedatetime = CNodes[i]["geofencedatetime"].InnerText;
                        string transporter = CNodes[i]["transporter"].InnerText;
                        string odometer = CNodes[i]["odometer"].InnerText;
                        string hvinp = CNodes[i]["hvinp"].InnerText;

                        string return_result = Insert_Bt_Running(vehicle, uid, vehicleinfo, gpsupdatedtime, latitude, longitude, location, speed, stop, geofencelocation, geofenceinout, geofencedatetime, transporter, odometer, hvinp);
                    }
                    break;
                }


                //if (vehicle != "error")
                //{
                //    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("", conn);
                //    cmd.CommandText = "delete from btrack.bt_vehicle_location where vehicle_id='" + Convert.ToString(dtSettings.Rows[i]["bus_id"]) + "';";
                //    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                //    {
                //        conn.Open();
                //    }

                //    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //}



            //}
        }
        return vehicle_detail;
    }



    public string convert_xml(string result, string tagname)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] tag = tagname.Split('/');

            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.LoadXml(result);
            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName(tag[0].ToString());
            string Short_Fall = string.Empty;
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                Short_Fall = node.InnerText;
            }
            xmldoc.LoadXml(Short_Fall);
            XmlNodeList nodeList1 = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName(tag[1].ToString());
            string return_result = string.Empty;
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList1)
            {
                return_result = node.InnerText;
            }
            return return_result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "error";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please share the full error details you are getting?